# contact form slide toggle checkbox values

Tags: php, html, html-email, contact-form

I am using 2 yes/no slide toggle checkboxes via [CSS styling](http://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm) in a contact form.

I can't get the form to send any value other than what I state in the HTML. If I click the slide and it moves to "no", it will send me an email with "yes", not "no".

How can I get it to post either yes or no, depending on where the slide is?

**HTML**

```
<div class="contactAddContainer">
    <div class="contactAdd">    
        <input type="checkbox" value="add" id="contactAdd" name="contactAdd" checked/>
        <label for="contactAdd"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="contactAddText">Add me to your email list.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contactRemoveContainer">
    <div class="contactRemove"> 
        <input type="checkbox" value="remove" id="contactRemove" name="contactRemove" checked/>
        <label for="contactRemove"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="contactRemoveText">Remove me from your email list.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=checkbox] {visibility:hidden;}
.contactAddContainer, contactRemoveContainer {width:100%; margin:0 auto; text-align:left;}
.contactAdd, .contactRemove {width:80px; height:26px; background:transparent; margin:10px 0; border-radius:0px; position:relative; border:1px solid #2C3E50; vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block;}
.contactAdd::after, .contactRemove::after {content:'NO'; font-size:12px; line-height:26px; font-family:Open Sans; color:#EBEBEB; position:absolute; right:10px; top:0; z-index:0;}
.contactAdd::before, .contactRemove::before {content:'YES'; font-size:12px; line-height:26px; font-family:Open Sans; color:#FFD95F; position:absolute; top:0; left:10px; z-index:0;}
.contactAdd label:hover, .contactRemove label:hover {background:#FFD95F;}
.contactAddText, .contactRemoveText {font-family:Open Sans; font-size:13px; text-align:left; vertical-align:middle; display:inline-block; padding:0 0 0 10px; color:#EBEBEB;}
.contactAdd label {display:block; width:34px; height:20px; border-radius:0px; -webkit-transition:all .4s ease; transition:all .3s ease; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:3px; left:3px; z-index:1; background:#2C3E50;}
.contactAdd input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {left:43px;}
.contactRemove label {display:block; width:34px; height:20px; border-radius:0px; -webkit-transition:all .4s ease; transition:all .3s ease; cursor:pointer; position:absolute; top:3px; right:3px; z-index:1; background:#2C3E50;}
.contactRemove input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {right:43px;}
```

**PHP**

```
$subscribe= $_POST['contactAdd'];
$unsubscribe= $_POST['contactRemove'];
$email_message .= "<tr style='font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;'><td width='110' style='padding:10px 10px; color:#666; border-right:1px solid #CCC; vertical-align:top;'>SUBSCRIBE </td><td style='padding-left:10px;'>" .$subscribe."</td></tr>";
$email_message .= "<tr style='font-family:Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px;'><td width='110' style='padding:10px 10px; color:#666; border-right:1px solid #CCC; vertical-align:top;'>UNSUBSCRIBE </td><td style='padding-left:10px;'>" .$unsubscribe."</td></tr>";
```

**FORM ACTION (jQuery in HTML page)**

```
<script>
// hide response initially
$('#contactResponse').hide();
// start submit
$('#contactForm').submit(function(event) 
    {
    // stop form submit
    event.preventDefault();
    // get values from page
    var $form = $( this ),
        $submit = $form.find( 'button[type="submit"]' ),
        fname_value = $form.find( 'input[name="firstName"]' ).val(),
        lname_value = $form.find( 'input[name="lastName"]' ).val(),
        phone_value = $form.find( 'input[name="phoneNumber"]' ).val(),
        email_value = $form.find( 'input[name="emailAddress"]' ).val(),
        message_value = $form.find( 'textarea[name="message"]' ).val(),
        contactAdd_value = $form.find( 'input[name="contactAdd"]' ).val(),
        contactRemove_value = $form.find( 'input[name="contactRemove"]' ).val(),
        url = $form.attr('action');
    // send data
    var posting = $.post( url, { 
        firstName: fname_value, 
        lastName: lname_value,
        emailAddress: email_value, 
        phoneNumber: phone_value,
        message: message_value,
        contactAdd: contactAdd_value,
        contactRemove: contactRemove_value
    });
    posting.done(function( data )
    {
        // show response
        $('#contactResponse').delay(1000).fadeIn(500).html(data);
        // after submit hide submit button and fade inputs
        $('input[name=submit]').fadeOut(500);
        $('input[name=firstName], input[name=lastName], input[name=phoneNumber], input[name=emailAddress], textarea[name=message], .contactRemoveContainer, .contactAddContainer').fadeOut(500);
        $('input[name=reset]').fadeOut(500);
        $('input[name=reset]').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
        // show submit and hide response on reset
        $('.reset').click(function(){
            $('input[name=submit]').stop().delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
            //$('input[name=reset]').stop().fadeOut(500);
            //$('input[name=reset]').stop().delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
            $('#contactResponse').fadeOut(500);
            $('input[name=firstName], input[name=lastName], input[name=phoneNumber], input[name=emailAddress], textarea[name=message],  .contactRemoveContainer, .contactAddContainer').stop().delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you post the form action html ?

Comment: Added what I "think" you meant...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some Javascript..

You have hard-coded the checkboxes as 'checked', so they will send their value every time you submit the form.  CSS makes it look different.. ..but that is all it does.  You cannot 'unckeck' a checkbox with CSS.

So, in answer to your question : use Javascript.

Comment: I posted my form action code which is jQuery that resides on my HTML page before `</body>`. Does that help?

Comment: It doesn't help you.. there is nothing in there except an `onSubmit()` function.

Comment: (p.s. - i get the same result regardless of `checked` being hard-coded in the HTML.)

Comment: Checkboxes don't submit their value, unless checked.

Comment: That's what I thought, but whether or not I hard-code `checked` and whether or not I check the box...it still sends the input `value` and shows up in the resulting email.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it.

(1) Removed the hard-coded `checked` from HTML.
(2) Changed variables in jQuery from:

```
contactAdd_value = $form.find( 'input[name="contactAdd"]' ).val(),
contactRemove_value = $form.find( 'input[name="contactRemove"]' ).val(),
```

to:

```
contactAdd_value = $('#contactAdd').is(':checked') ? $("#contactAdd").val() : null,
contactRemove_value = $('#contactRemove').is(':checked') ? $("#contactRemove").val() : null,
```

Works great now.